Webforms and CiviCRM Contribution page to prevent transaction spam - disable page?
Looking at the Webform documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/webform/ , I see it says

When creating a contribution, event or membership webform that includes payments, first set up a dedicated contribution page for the sole purpose of embedding it on one or more webforms for contributions or memberships.

(I'm using CiviCRM 5.74 and Drupal 10. I know the page above is for Drupal 7 but I'm hoping the general setup is similar. I'm hoping to help with updating the Drupal 8/9/10 version of the WebForm doc if I can get this working.)
Our biggest reason for setting up a contribution using Webforms instead of just using the CiviCRM contribution page is transaction spam - when we turned on donation forms in CiviCRM, we got huge amounts of fake transactions. Before moving to CiviCRM, we were able to block those kinds of problems using built-in Drupal anti-spam modules like Honeypot. (Attempting to use the CiviCRM anti-spam plugins hasn't solved the problem for us.)
My question:
When setting up a CiviCRM contribution page just to embed it in a Webform, is it okay to make the page inactive? Will the embed still work?
If not, how do we keep bots from discovering and using the contribution page for bad spam transactions, which is what we need to avoid?
Thank you!

If setting it to inactive doesn't work you could use https://civicrm.org/extensions/form-protection

Drupal 8 - 11 do not require a civi contribution page to be used.

From Drupal 8 onwards webform_civicrm does not require (or allow) that the webform be linked to a civi contribution page.
Receipting options are available via the webform_civicrm contribution tab.
